# Null Connectionstring

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write a solution in VS2010 that have some C# and asp.net project in it.

I have a configuration class in C# project to make connectionstring for connect to database and it worked well in C# projects,
But when I want to use it in Asp web forms the class return a null connectionstring!!!

Please help me because I can't find anything about this problem in web.

Is that need to write another class and using web.config to make connectionstring for asp projects?? or I can reuse class of C# projects for asp projects??

```
 protected void Button_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.intCreatedID = Aryana.Data.Contact.Create(int.Parse(Aryana.Data.FormPublicSetting.GetOption("DefaultGroup"));
        }
```

///The Method to load data from db(the connectionstring in this method return null

```
 public static string GetOption(string title)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Aryana.Data.Configuration.ConnectionString))
             {
                 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SET NOCOUNT OFF SELECT Content FROM [dbo].[DefaultSetting] WHERE (Title = @Title)", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);

                connection.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                   if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string value = (string)dr["Content"];
                        return value;
                    }
                    else
                        throw new ObjectDisposedException("title");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

/// The method to make connectionstring

```
 public static class Configuration
{
    static Configuration()
    {

        string ServerName = Properties.Settings.Default.Server;
        string DataBaseName = Properties.Settings.Default.DataBaseName;

connectionString = "data source=" + ServerName + "; initial catalog=" + DataBaseName + ";user id=sa;";
```

Comment: what is the piece of code that you used in asp webforms?

Comment: kindly use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55094239/edit) to edit the post and add the code you are using to get the connection string from the configuration file.

Comment: Its not clear what you have done in C# project and asp.net project. So it is very difficult to guess what's not right and what needs to be corrected. So you need to share the relevant code in question itself and tell us what exact issue you are facing?

Comment: I add this code and the problem solved :     string ConnStr = Configuration.ConnectionString;
            if (ConnStr == null) { ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStrWeb"].ConnectionString; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get connection string from web.config file

web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="connection string goes here"  />   
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and you can then get the connection string in c# code with:

```
string connString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

`ConfigurationManager` class in is `System.Configuration` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your Help.I change my code to when my connectionstring is null use that from web.config as mentioned you.